# How can I find out what kind of file this is?

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++

I have [this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kif6wdoq5txebcr/download?dl=1) file, and I have absolutely no idea what kind of file it is.

When I open it in Notepad++ it reads as

```
ð    X      döS
```

**or**

[image: http://gyazo.com/d156217b86512943d494f908b74c050e.png]

How can I figure out what this is, and how to modfiy it?

Comment: The file originates [here](http://patch.us.wizard101.com:12500).

Comment: Why do you need to modify the file?

Comment: It's a patcher file for a game. When you login, it runs a patcher, which checks if all the files are up to date. I want to take a few files out of the patcher so I can run the game with custom files. @Dennis

Comment: Without decompiling the game/updater, it will be hard to figure out what exactly this patcher file is supposed to do. It certainly does not contain any MD5 sums...

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to modify this then. Can you perform the patch and then update the files in the game directory? Also, if the patcher is looking for an MD5 sum then any modification you could make wouldn't be accepted by the patcher anyway as this would change the MD5.

Comment: I'm not sure if replacing the files while the game is running will work; it might just crash it. As for the MD5 sums, I'm fairly sure it doesn't check.

Comment: it is a binary file. If it is possible, it would need to be done with a utility like this one: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have some unidentified file, the best way I know to analyze it (at least using a computer-scientific method) is the program [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) from *Marco Pontello*.
According to its definition:

> TrID is an utility designed to identify file types from their binary
>   signatures.

Example:

```
C:\TrID>trid c:\test\doc\lasik_info.doc
 TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.10 - (C) 2003-11 By M.Pontello          
 Collecting data from file: c:\test\doc\lasik_info.doc
 Definitions found: 4150
 Analyzing...
  70.7% (.DOC) Microsoft Word document (58000/1/5)
  29.3% (.) Generic OLE2 / Multistream Compound File (24000/1)
```

Latest version (**27/02/14**) includes 5.276 file types.
A real must-have program if you use to need file type identification.
Saddly, I must admit that, with this your file, has no results:

```
c:\Temp\trid.exe download
TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.02 - (C) 2003-06 By M.Pontello
Definitions found:  5276
Analyzing...
Collecting data from file: C:\Temp\download
       Unknown!
```

Additional points:

- **Versions** for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It's a binary data.  I don't touch windows so I'm unsure what utilities you can use to edit it, but you need a hex editor.

```
claw:~ jonv$ file download
download: data
claw:~ jonv$ strings download
claw:~ jonv$ hexdump download
0000000 0d f0 13 00 01 00 00 00 58 09 00 00 00 00 64 f6
0000010 02 53 7f 01 00 00 00
0000017
```

Comment: What is the above code? @yoonix

Comment: It's machine-readable data represented in hex format.  It most likely was never intended for human consumption.  Without knowing the file's intended purpose, you aren't going to be able to know what the data stands for.